# jQuery -Wildcard Selector Starts w/String and ends w/Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-selectors

I've been looking all over the web for an example or solution, but have not been successful yet.  The challenge I am facing is using jQuery to select an element ID that starts with a string, but also ends with a variable passed in by a function.

**Example:**

.JSP file - There is a ForEach loop that creates dynamic divs and adds a variable ${number} to their 'id' as a key.  This allows a button to show/hide only that unique div without impacting other divs on the same page.

```
<div id="success-icon${number}"></div>
<div id="success-msg${number}"><p>My Message</p></div>

<button id="success-btn${number}" onclick="showIcon(${number})">Show Button ${number}</button>
```

.JS file

```
//does not work, because it is looking for success+number
function showIcon(number){
    $('[id^=success]'+number).show();
}
```

I need it to look for an id that starts with "success" and ends with "number" variable.

Would really appreciate any help on this and thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use as selector:

```
$('[id^=success][id$='+number+']').show();
```

But beware, would match for `number = 1;` both `div`s with IDs: `success-icon1` and e.g `success-icon11`. Now that's depend your expected behaviour.

Anyway, to 'group' some elements, you would have better to use a common class specific to each grouped element.

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I was looking for.